# What packages are required to open images?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I am starting to learn image processing with Python. There seem to be a lot of files to install first, from what I understand of various documentation I have read.

Can you tell me if I need all these packages installed before I can open an image (I am running Python 3.7.1 and installed the Anaconda distribution) or is there an easier way?

1. cv3
2. Pillow
3. Wheels for windows

Comment: Why don't you find a good tutorial? Just google it.

Comment: The tutorials I have found assume you have the packages already loaded and just briefly mention them and instead focus on the code.

Comment: Then why not install them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
    import numpy
    import cv2
```

For using `cv2` you'll have to install OpenCV in your computer. If you use Anaconda Navigator you can install the OpenCV package in a new environment using the `conda install opencv` command. 
You can also use:

```
    from PIL import Image
```

Here's an example. This program uses `PIL` methods to filter only the red channel from an RGB image:

```
    from PIL import Image
    def redChannel(img):
        newImage = Image.new('RGB', img.size)
        for y in range(img.height):
             for x in range(img.width):
             pixel = img.getpixel((x,y))
             newImage.putpixel((x,y),(pixel[0],0,0))
        return newImage

    andromeda = Image.open('Andromeda-Galaxy-Wallpaper.jpg')
    andromeda_redCh= redChannel(andromeda)
    andromeda.show()
    andromeda_redCh.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to open an image, make a few changes to its numpy array and possibly save it as a new image, then Pillow is enough. OpenCV (it is `cv2` btw, not `cv3`, even for opencv 3 and above) is used for more advanced processing, like edge detection, colorspace conversion and warping to name just a few. For your purposes it seems like Pillow should be enough.

Comment: Thank you Jaiyman. I only want to do basic stuff for now. Do you recommend a good download site for a windows machine and version 3.7.1. cheers

Comment: You should be able to use `conda install -c anaconda pillow` from the command line to install compatible version of pillow. Since you are already using anaconda, there is no need to look anywhere else. See [this](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pillow) site, in case you have trouble

Comment: I typed the command "import PIL
from PIL import image"  and I could write simple script to manipulate png images. I wanted to use Pillow but PIL seems to do the tasks I need. thank you.